# Tornado with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, io, tornado

I have setup that uses `Tornado` as http server and custom made http framework. Idea is to have single tornado handler and every request that arrives should be just submitted to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and leave `Tornado` to listen for new requests. Once thread finishes processing request, callback is called that sends response to client in same thread where IO loop is being executes.

Stripped down, code looks something like this. Base http server class:

```
class HttpServer():
    def __init__(self, router, port, max_workers):
        self.router = router
        self.port = port
        self.max_workers = max_workers

    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Tornado backed implementation of HttpServer:

```
class TornadoServer(HttpServer):
    def run(self):
        executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.max_workers)

        def submit(callback, **kwargs):
            future = executor.submit(Request(**kwargs))
            future.add_done_callback(callback)
            return future

        application = web.Application([
            (r'(.*)', MainHandler, {
                'submit': submit,
                'router': self.router   
            })
        ])

        application.listen(self.port)

        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Main handler that handles all tornado requests (implemented only GET, but other would be the same):

```
class MainHandler():
    def initialize(self, submit, router):
        self.submit = submit
        self.router = router

    def worker(self, request):
        responder, kwargs = self.router.resolve(request)
        response = responder(**kwargs)
        return res

    def on_response(self, response):
        # when this is called response should already have result
        if isinstance(response, Future):
            response = response.result()
        # response is my own class, just write returned content to client
        self.write(response.data)
        self.flush()
        self.finish()

    def _on_response_ready(self, response):
        # schedule response processing in ioloop, to be on ioloop thread
        ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(
            partial(self.on_response, response)
        )

    @web.asynchronous
    def get(self, url):
        self.submit(
            self._on_response_ready, # callback
            url=url, method='post', original_request=self.request
        )
```

Server is started with something like:

```
router = Router()
server = TornadoServer(router, 1111, max_workers=50)
server.run()
```

So, as you can see, main handler just submits every request to thread pool and when processing is done, callback is called (`_on_response_ready`) which just schedules request finish to be executed on IO loop (to make sure that it is done on same thread where IO loop is being executed).

This works. At least it looks like it does.

My problem here is performance regarding max workers in ThreadPoolExecutor.

All handlers are IO bound, there is no computation going on (they are mostly waiting for DB or external services), so with 50 workers I would expect 50 concurent requests to finish approximately 50 times faster then 50 concurent requests with only one worker.

But that is not the case. What I see is almost identical requests per second when I have 50 workers in thread pool and 1 worker.

For measuring, I have used Apache-Bench with something like:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost:1111/some_url
```

Does anybody have idea what am I doing wrong? Did I misunderstand how Tornado or ThreadPool works? Or combination?

Comment: This code looks more or less correct to me. How exactly are the 50 workers doing their I/O? How many QPS are you seeing? Could the HTTP processing in the IOLoop thread be the bottleneck?

Comment: @BenDarnell, I/O in workers is mostly querying database and calling external services. HTTP processing in IOLoop is quite minimal (measuring shows that it takes much less time then actual processing (1 or 2 percents). If QPS means Queries Per Second, where Query is DB query, then one or two queries are performed per HTTP request.

Comment: What libraries are you using for the database queries? Could there be a C library that fails to release the GIL while blocking on I/O?

Comment: I am using SqlAlchemy with Postgres and psycopg2... I did not find anywhere in documentation that psycogp2 or SqlAlchemy can do this, so it did not cross my mind. I have just tested with pg8000 (pure python postgres driver), I am getting same behaviour.

Comment: I am using tornado + momoko, one thread, one process, and the bottleneck for me is the pool_size and the db times, not tornado

Comment: I would go with nginx + many Tornado upstreams

Comment: @kAlmAcetA I ended up writing something similar with TornadoServer class from question that is WSGI compliant and I am using uwsgi as application server and nginx as http server. Dropped Tornado completely. Now performance increases with number of workers, as expected.

Comment: what is **Request** passed to **executor.submit()** method in **TornadoServer.submit()**?

Comment: Request is my class which does not contain anything much. It is basically container for request data (contains original tornado request and some additional data used by my application).

Comment: I am not sure if the slow performance was caused by **Request()** passed to executor.submit(). So could you attempt to use time.sleep(10) instead to test.

Comment: What if instead of I/O operations or database queries, we conduct heavy computations. Despite using @gen.coroutine decorator but without ThreadPoolExecutor my IOLoop is completely blocked. Should I move all computationally heavy work to executors?

Comment: How long does your program take when it pass `Request()` instance to threadpool

Answer (score 1):

The momoko wrapper for postgres remedies this issue, as suggested by kwarunek. If you want to solicit further debugging advice from outside collaborators, it would help to post timestamped debug logs from a test task that does sleep(10) before each DB access.